# Using wildcard in SUMIF function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, wildcard

I have two worksheets Sheet1 and Sheet2. On Sheet1 I have a list of ItemNumber that I need to populate with inventory level (column East). I have to pull the information from column East from Sheet2. If the ItemNumber column on sheet2 contains the value of ItemNumber string from sheet1, then to sum all the quantity for East on Sheet1. I tried using SumIf function in my VBA code with the wildcard but all my values are returning as 0 on Sheet1. Can someone advise on how to correct this? Very much appreciated

On Sheet1:

```
Item Number East
WidgetA 
WidgetB 
WidgetC 
WidgetD
```

Sheet2 data:

```
Item Number East
WidgetA-1         1
WidgetA-2         2
WidgetA-3         3
WidgetB           2
WidgetB-1         4
WidgetC           1
WidgetD-1     1 
WidgetD-2         1
```

My code:

```
Dim i as Integer
Dim ItemNumber, East As Double

Do While Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""

ItemNumber = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
East = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Sheet2.Range("B:B"), """*" & ItemNumber & "*""", Sheet2.Range("Q:Q"))
Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value = East


i = i + 1


Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are searching in the ranges you are, as those ranges do not match your example provided.  I changed the ranges, declared ItemNumber as a String instead of a Double, and gave "i" a starting value of 2 to account for the column header.  You also seemed to have extra quotations preceding the wildcard character.  Hope this helps.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim ItemNumber As String
Dim East As Double
    i = 2
    Do While Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
        ItemNumber = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        East = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Sheet2.Range("A:A"), "*" & _
             ItemNumber & "*", Sheet2.Range("B:B"))
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = East
        i = i + 1
    Loop
```

Comment: By mere seconds!  Phew, that was a close one.  I'd say we were both on to something as the answers we gave are practically identical.

Comment: I just kept the original ranges (I assumed that is where his details were despite the examples given)

Comment: Honestly, I assumed that too.  But for the sake of teaching future Google searchers who stumble upon this, removing the ambiguity will benefit the masses.

Comment: Would there be any confusion given that the OP has different columns than the answer provided?

Comment: The first sentence in my answer should avoid any confusion.